# Does derived class share the vtable with base class, when derived class does not over-ride the virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Cases as below where the derived class have no definition of the virtual function.
In such cases do the derived class and base class share the same the `vtable`, or the derived class will have its another `vtable`, making the total `vtable` count to 2?

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void fun()
        {
            cout<<"A's defination"<<endl;
        }
};

class B: public A
{
};

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(B)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Haven't got a concrete answer yet. In some links I have seen 'derived class and base class can share a vtable' where as some other page 'No two class share a `vtable`.'

Please help me understand the actual behavior.

Comment: Does the C++ language standard even define the term `VTable`? I would expect this to be compiler-implementation dependent. You can simply check the `sizeof(B)` and find out, but if my guess is correct, then you might get different results on different compilers.

Comment: @barak sizeof(B) is 8, justifying that it contains a vptr. Does the vptr of B, in this case, points to vtable of  class A ?

Comment: If you're running on a 32-bit platform, then it actually justifies the opposite of what you just said.

Comment: @barak: running on a 64 bit, Suse linux box.